# run block of code that was generated asynchronously, 'only' when a specific view controller is visible and in control

Tags: ios

When my program receives a notification/event (asynchronously) I might need to display an alert.  However, I do not know what view controller will be in control when I receive the notification - I have seen posts that show how to present a alertController at any time regardless of what view controller is on screen. What I 'think' I want to do is to defer the display of the alert until a specific view controller is visible.  (The other view controllers are modal and probably should not be interrupted.)  One way, I think I can do this, is to send the blocks to the specified view controller, save them in an array and then requeue them to the main_queue as I transition to the controller (i.e prepareForSegue ) This approach seems kludgy ! Any advise ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to stick to MVC: store your notification in some data structure. Have your view controller use that data structure as the M in MVC. When the viewController notices a change in the data / model, it can respond to it. You might use a BOOL flag flipped in viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear if you would need to kick of some animation when the view appears.
When you start to pass around blocks in the way you describe, you need to be extremely well-organized and know exactly what you are doing, as it can lead to very-hard-to-debug code if done wrongly.

Simply put: try to see the M, V and C in your situation, and you should be fine.